# 402 while doing payment using debit with Stripe gateway

Tags: php, android, wordpress, stripe-payments, mobile-application

We have used Stripe payment gateway. We face 402 error while doing transaction using debit card with Android application It works fine if payment is done using credit card.

402  is bank decline error.Is there anyone who faced this same error?

Will be glad if anyone can be helpful.

Comment: Are you sure that this same debit card _could_ be used provided it's not on a mobile?

Comment: There's a more specific error that's returned, and you can look up the specific decline code in [Stripe's docs](https://stripe.com/docs/declines/codes) to determine how best to handle it. Ultimately you'll likely need to ask the customer to reach out to their bank, as they are best placed to know why it declined.

Answer (score 0):

**402 - Request Failed  The parameters were valid but the request failed.**

402 error occurs when the credit card information you have input is not correct. 
Cross check the **card number**, **expiration date**, etc and try to submit again:

Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239339/why-does-stripe-com-return-error-402-payment-required)

Stripe [testing](https://stripe.com/docs/testing)